# pyparsing a string with operator precedence

Tags: pyparsing

I would like to use pyparsing module for parsing expressions such as:

*carbo * or oxy * or nitro **

Once parsed, those expressions should be transformed to:

*carbo(universe).select([*]) | oxy(universe).select([*]) | nitro(universe).select([*])*

for a further eval.

I built a grammar that works only for the first *or* found in the string but not for the subsequent ones. Here is my grammar:

```
from pyparsing import *

def parse_keyword(token):

    return '"%s"(universe).select' % token[0]

def parse_arguments(token):

    return "(%s)" % str(token)

def operator_and(token):

    token[0][1] = "&"

    return " ".join(token[0])

def operator_or(token):

    token[0][1] = "|"

    return " ".join(token[0])

def parse_expression(self, token):

    return "".join([str(t) for t in token])

expression = 'carbo * or oxy * or nitro *'

linkers   = oneOf(["and","or",], caseless=True)
keyword   = oneOf(['carbo','oxy','nitro'], caseless=True).setParseAction(parse_keyword)
arguments = Optional(~linkers + delimitedList(Word(printables,excludeChars=","),combine=False)).setParseAction(parse_arguments)

selector = OneOrMore((keyword+arguments))

grammar = Forward()

grammar << selector.setParseAction(parse_expression)

grammar = operatorPrecedence(grammar, [(oneOf(["and"],caseless=True), 2, opAssoc.LEFT , operator_and),
                                       (oneOf(["or"] ,caseless=True), 2, opAssoc.LEFT , operator_or)],
                             lpar="(",
                             rpar=")")

parsedExpression = grammar.transformString(expression)

print parsedExpression
```

would you have any idea about what is wrong with it ?

thanks

Eric

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the grammar was the use of LEFT association instead of RIGHT in the operator precedence definition.
Here is the final grammar that does the job:

```
from pyparsing import *

def parse_keyword(token):

    return '"%s"(universe).select' % token[0]

def parse_arguments(token):

    return "(%s)" % str(token)

def operator_and(token):

    token[0][1] = "&"

    return " ".join(token[0])

def operator_or(token):

    token[0][1] = "|"

    return " ".join(token[0])

def parse_expression(self, token):

    return "".join([str(t) for t in token])

expression = 'carbo * or oxy * or nitro *'

linkers   = oneOf(["and","or",], caseless=True)
keyword   = oneOf(['carbo','oxy','nitro'], caseless=True).setParseAction(parse_keyword)
arguments = Optional(~linkers + delimitedList(Word(printables,excludeChars=","),combine=False)).setParseAction(parse_arguments)

selector = OneOrMore((keyword+arguments))

grammar = Forward()

grammar << selector.setParseAction(parse_expression)

grammar = operatorPrecedence(grammar, [(oneOf(["and"],caseless=True), 2, opAssoc.RIGHT , operator_and),
                                       (oneOf(["or"] ,caseless=True), 2, opAssoc.RIGHT , operator_or)],
                             lpar="(",
                             rpar=")")

parsedExpression = grammar.transformString(expression)
```

The difference is subtle (and still a bit unclear for me) but it works.

Eric